# Need ONE end to end example of using Backbone.js and restful webservice in java

Tags: rest, backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone-events, backbone-model

I have just started working with backbone.js and facing some problem in retrieving the data from the Restful webservices in java and giving it to the model.

I searched on internet but could not find a good reference showing one end to end flow.

If anyone can share any references then i will be very thankful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/using-backbone-js-with-a-restful-java-back-end/) is a good intro. It's all on Github as well.